# Can you enforce the creation of a static variable on a Java Interface?

Tags: java

In android I have a base activity class that has some added functionality that I use on most my activities.

This depends on the user having declared a tag for the activity, so I have (right now ) something like this:

```
public abstract class CoreActivity extends Activity {
   protected abstract void TAG();
}
```

but I have seen that Parcelable depends on it having a static variable called CREATOR that all implementations must have.

Is there a way to enforce something like this in my class?

Comment: No.............

Comment: If all the classes that extend `CoreActivity` have a common piece of code that uses `CREATOR`, that piece of code should be implemented in `CoreActivity`